# Addressing a specific occurrence of a character in sed

Tags: parsing, csv, sed, awk

How do I remove or address a specific occurrence of a character in sed?

I'm editing a CSV file and I want to remove all text between the third and the fifth occurrence of the comma (that is, dropping fields four and five) . Is there any way to achieve this using sed?

E.g:

```
% cat myfile
one,two,three,dropthis,dropthat,six,...

% sed -i 's/someregex//' myfile

% cat myfile
one,two,three,,six,...
```

Comment: If you really have CSV (e.g. where comma delimiters can be protected with quotes) then no, not without a ton of code as regular expressions are insufficient for parsing CSV. `sed` being a Turing complete language can in principle compute any computable function, but it is far, far easier to use a real parser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is okay to consider `cut` command then:

```
$ cut -d, -f1-3,6- file
```

Comment: The simplest answer is probably the best.

Answer (score 2):

`awk`  or any other tools that are able to split strings on delimiters are better for the job than `sed`

```
$ cat file
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -ne 's=$_.split(","); s[2,3]=nil ;puts s.compact.join(",") ' file
1,2,6,7,8,9,10
```

using awk

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$3=$4=$5="";}{gsub(/,,*/,",")}1'  file
1,2,6,7,8,9,10
```

Comment: `awk` is far better suited to field processing, but consider the input string `1, "2,2", 3, 4, 5, 6`. You also made the same fencepost error I did in my first stab at "remove all text between the third and the fifth comma", that is drop field 4.

Comment: I agree with you. Such cases need to be taken care of. But as always, we delve too deep into these things that conflicts arise because of insufficient information. If OP's data does not have such cases, then using simple splitting would do. Otherwise, using a real parser like that supported by Python/Ruby/Perl should be the wiser choice. All these are up to the OP's discretion.

Comment: @msw: "remove all text between the third and the fifth comma", means drop fields four *and five* (between the third and fourth would drop the fourth column). Which is what my answer does.

Answer (score 2):

A real parser in action

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import sys

cr = csv.reader(open('my-data.csv', 'rb'))
cw = csv.writer(open('stripped-data.csv', 'wb'))

for row in cr:
    cw.writerow(row[0:3] + row[5:])
```

But do note the [preface to the csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html):

> The so-called CSV (Comma Separated
>   Values) format is the most common
>   import and export format for
>   spreadsheets and databases. There is
>   no “CSV standard”, so the format is
>   operationally defined by the many
>   applications which read and write it.
>   The lack of a standard means that
>   subtle differences often exist in the
>   data produced and consumed by
>   different applications. These
>   differences can make it annoying to
>   process CSV files from multiple
>   sources. Still, while the delimiters
>   and quoting characters vary, the
>   overall format is similar enough that
>   it is possible to write a single
>   module which can efficiently
>   manipulate such data, hiding the
>   details of reading and writing the
>   data from the programmer.

```
$ cat my-data.csv
1
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,3,4,
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6,
1,2,,4,5,6
1,2,"3,3",4,5,6
1,"2,2",3,4,5,6
,,3,4,5
,,,4,5
,,,,5
$ python csvdrop.py
$ cat stripped-data.csv
1
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3,6
1,2,3,6,
1,2,,6
1,2,"3,3",6
1,"2,2",3,6
,,3
,,
,,
```

Comment: +1 for using a 'real' parser. But you need to drop fields four and five.

Comment: thanks, fixed (for the fourth time, going to sleep now I promise)